# Logistic regression demonstration with one preditor

Tags: regression, logistic

I got an assignment from which nothing is clear for me.

I have the following logistic regression formula:

[image: log reg]

and what I am struggling in understanding how to do is to the to prove that this equation is true for binary logistic regression with one continuous predictor.

What should I do? Should I plug inside some values and solve it?
Moreover, I don't understand what does pie stands for, what does it denotate?

Comment: pi is P(the response is 1|x_i).

Comment: What do you mean by `1|x_i)`?